# Add Opacity to Part of an Image (CSS)

Tags: css

How can one add opacitiy to just the left `100px` of a `600px` wide image in css? Is there a `css` property for that?

I have tried to add an overlapping `div` and add opacity to this `div`, but that is a pain in the back and does not look as a good solution.

Comment: I'd do it with a clipping masks and absolute positioned pseudo elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well i found that overlapping div with `position:absolute` is the only solution for this because their is no property in css to catch half image.

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div id="opacity_div"></div>
    <img class="half_fade" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7mPR.jpg?s=32&g=1">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent{
   position:relative;
}
#opacity_div{
   background:#fff;
   height:20px;
   width:20px;
   position:absolute;
   top:18px;
   left:6px;
   opacity:0.5 /* manipulate to desired opacity */
}
img.half_fade {
   position:absolute;
   top:0;left:0;
   z-index:-1000;
}
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/JMBFS/81/

Checkout this question to understand better : https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/70025/how-to-apply-opacity-to-just-a-portion-of-the-image/70029

Comment: This answer is wrong. I am sorry. There is a CSS solution in the form of the 'clip' and 'clip-path' properties. The 'clip' property can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.asp and has excellent browser support. The 'clip-path' property can be found here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path and still has very limited browser support.

Comment: @JoostS Clip Property is already deprecated bro https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clip and what will you do for IE browser support

Comment: The 'clip' property is in the CSS2.1 specification and MDN states that "... the clip-path property replaces the now deprecated clip property". So please change your answer to a correct one! If you have an opinion about using them, please be clear about it. Write something like: "There are two properties, but I would not use them because..."

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use overlay the image element with another image element, using position absolute and clipping (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqpwgV).

HTML:

```
<img src="img.jpg" id="image-overlay" />
<img src="img.jpg" id="image" />
```

CSS:

```css
#image-overlay{position:absolute;clip: rect(0px,498px,374px,100px);}
#image{opacity:0.5;}
```

If you want to be future ready. Use clip-path with graceful degradation in your CSS. See code below (or http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqLdxW).

```css
#image-overlay{position:absolute; 
  clip: rect(0px,498px,374px,100px);
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(0px 0px 0px 100px);
  clip-path: inset(0px 0px 0px 100px);
  }
#image{opacity:0.5;}
```

Comment: [`clip` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clip), and [`clip-path` has bad browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path).